# How to bypass restrictions on (system) internal sound recording, rooted 4.4.4 android

Tags: root-access, microphone, audio-recording, video-conference

I have installed an app called "SCR Pro", it allows to record android screen as video with internal sound, or microphone, or mute.
With youtube as example, it can record video with internal sound and without microphone (exterior sounds) WITHOUT problems.
But with Paltalk or Join.me, when it begins to record, it fails to record the internal sound, it obligates me to continue recording as mute or it stopps.
It says "Only one app can use microphone
at a time. This is an Android
system limitation. Close other app
using the microphone (e.g. Google
Now or Skype) or continue
recording without audio".

I have Android 4.4.4 rooted, I tried to deactivate "Ok Google" service, and I have no Skype App in device, but it still not recording internal sound ONLY with Paltalk or Join.me.

How to bypass this restriction on microphone use in Android?

Thanks for any help!